# BFS for pacman ghost

Tags: java, breadth-first-search, pacman

I've been several days with this problem.
I've searched in this forum, and in google for a solution without any luck.
My problem is I am not able to make a working BFS algorithm for managing the behaviour of a pacman ghost. I think I am ignoring something in the code.
I'll paste the code here, if you can help me you'll be thanked :)
pacman is number 2, and ghost is number 3.

```
Queue<Tile> path = new LinkedList<>();
Tile start = new Tile(canvas.g1.x, canvas.g1.y, 3);
Tile end = new Tile(canvas.pacman.x, canvas.pacman.y, 2);
start.distance = 1;
path.add(start);

while (!path.isEmpty()) {
    Tile current = path.remove();
    System.out.println(path.size());
    canvas.walls[current.y][current.x] = 0;
    if (canvas.walls[current.y][current.x] == canvas.walls[end.y][end.x]) {
        end = current;
        System.out.println("pacman found");
        break;
    }
    ArrayList<Tile> list = adyacent(current);
    for (Tile c : list) {
        if (c.distance == 0) {
            c.distance = current.distance + 1;
            path.add(c);
            canvas.walls[c.y][c.x] = 20;
            for (Tile v : path) {
                System.out.println("x: " + v.x + " / y: " + v.y + " / 
            distance: " + v.distance);
            }
        }
    }
}

int dist = end.distance;

System.out.println("Recolection ended, size: " + dist);
```

The class Tile():

```
public class Tile {

    public int x;
    public int y;
    public int distance;
    public int personaje;

    public Tile(int x, int y, int personaje) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.personaje = personaje;
        distance = 0;
    }
}
```

and the method adyacent():

in this method, the numbers I check are the ones with wall(each one with a diferent drawing))

```
public ArrayList<Tile> adyacent(Tile c) {

    ArrayList<Tile> surrounding = new ArrayList<>();
    int ant;
    ant = canvas.walls[c.y][c.x + 1];
    if ((ant != 7) && (ant != 8) && (ant != 9) && (ant != 11)
            && (ant != 12) && (ant != 13) && (ant != 14) && (ant != 15)
            && (ant != 16)) {
        surrounding.add(new Tile(c.x + 1, c.y, 3));
    }
    ant = canvas.walls[c.y][c.x - 1];
    if ((ant != 7) && (ant != 8) && (ant != 9) && (ant != 11)
            && (ant != 12) && (ant != 13) && (ant != 14) && (ant != 15)
            && (ant != 16)) {
        surrounding.add(new Tile(c.x - 1, c.y, 3));
    }
    ant = canvas.walls[c.y + 1][c.x];
    if ((ant != 7) && (ant != 8) && (ant != 9) && (ant != 11)
            && (ant != 12) && (ant != 13) && (ant != 14) && (ant != 15)
            && (ant != 16)) {
        surrounding.add(new Tile(c.x, c.y + 1, 3));
    }
    ant = canvas.walls[c.y - 1][c.x];
    if ((ant != 7) && (ant != 8) && (ant != 9) && (ant != 11)
            && (ant != 12) && (ant != 13) && (ant != 14) && (ant != 15)
            && (ant != 16)) {
        surrounding.add(new Tile(c.x, c.y - 1, 3));
    }
    return surrounding;
}
```

What I've observed is that it never reaches the System.out in which I return the size of the path. 
Also, where I see the size of the Queue, it seems right, but the System.out in which I see "x" and "y" and "distance" is bigger each time, much much bigger.

I set that the checked tiles change it's color, changing the number which I've got in the array: 0 is floor, 20 is transparent green. And it remains in center, and beggins to work slower and slower.

Forget to say that it never finds pacman :(
thanks!

Comment: to get the idea how this runs and wht the 7 8 13 mean we probably need to see it working

Comment: those number are the different tiles of wall, I wrote it just before, but I see its not very clear, sorry :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this morning I had a revelation and solved my own problem.

I had to create a boolean array to check if the tiles had been visited or not, and an int array for the distances.

With the booleans array I could be able to not visiting the visited tiles again, so the algorithm was able to finish.
With the distances array I was able to compare the distances to take the one which was smaller when checking in the second while. This way I was able to find the path.

Changing some things in the code allowed me to use both arrays to finally complete the program.

this is the code(variable names are in spanish because I am from spain and it was for class, but I know that I should code in english, and I usually do when I make my own projects):

```
    package comecocos;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

public class Ghost1Thread extends Thread {

    int x;
    int y;
    Juego canvas;
    Ventana ventana;
    boolean pause;
    int[][] control;
    int anterior;
    int acelerar;
    Pacman pacman;
    int ignorar;
    int salir;
    /*AUMENTA DE VELOCIDAD CUANDO PACMAN COME VARIOS PUNTOS*/

    public Ghost1Thread(Juego canvas, Ventana ventana) {
        this.canvas = canvas;
        this.ventana = ventana;
        this.pacman = canvas.pacman;
        this.control = canvas.paredes;
        pause = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            mover();
            canvas.repaint();
            try {
                sleep(acelerar);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println("Error durmiendo.");
            }
        }
    }

    public void mover() {
        if (!pause) {
            if (canvas.bolitas < 100 && canvas.g1.owned == false) {
                acelerar = 200;
            } else if ((canvas.bolitas < 100 && canvas.g1.owned == true) || (canvas.bolitas >= 100 && canvas.g1.owned == true)) {
                acelerar = 450;
            } else if (canvas.bolitas > 100 && canvas.g1.owned == false) {
                acelerar = 300;
            }
            if (canvas.g1.owned == false) {
                canvas.gh1[canvas.g1.y][canvas.g1.x] = 0;
                canvas.g1.x = buscar(canvas.pacman.x, canvas.pacman.y).x;
                canvas.g1.y = buscar(canvas.pacman.x, canvas.pacman.y).y;
                canvas.gh1[canvas.g1.y][canvas.g1.x] = 3;
            } else {
                if (canvas.pacman.x > canvas.g1.x) {
                    izquierda();
                } 
                if (canvas.pacman.x < canvas.g1.x) {
                    derecha();
                }
                if (canvas.pacman.y < canvas.g1.y) {
                    abajo();
                } 
                if (canvas.pacman.y > canvas.g1.y) {
                    arriba();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public Casilla buscar(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        Queue<Casilla> camino = new LinkedList<>();
        boolean [][] descubierto = new boolean[canvas.columnas][canvas.filas];
        int [][] distancias  = new int[canvas.columnas][canvas.filas];
        for (int i = 0; i < canvas.columnas; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < canvas.filas; j++) {
                descubierto[i][j] = false;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < canvas.columnas; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < canvas.filas; j++) {
                distancias[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
        Casilla inicio = new Casilla(canvas.g1.x, canvas.g1.y, 3);
        Casilla fin = new Casilla(x, y, 2);
        inicio.distancia = 1;
        camino.add(inicio);
        while (!camino.isEmpty()) {
            Casilla actual = camino.remove();
            if (canvas.paredes[actual.y][actual.x] == canvas.paredes[fin.y][fin.x]) {
                fin = actual;
            }
            ArrayList<Casilla> lista = adyacente(actual);
            for (Casilla c : lista) {
                if (c.distancia == 0 && descubierto[c.x][c.y] == false) {
                    c.distancia = actual.distancia + 1;
                    descubierto[c.x][c.y] = true;
                    distancias[c.x][c.y] = c.distancia;
                    camino.add(c);
                }
            }
        }
        int dist = fin.distancia;
        camino.add(fin);
        while (!camino.isEmpty()) {
            Casilla actual = camino.remove();
            ArrayList<Casilla> lista = adyacente(actual);
            for (Casilla c : lista) {
                if (distancias[c.x][c.y] < dist) {
                    if (distancias[c.x][c.y] == 2){
                        return c;
                    } else {
                        dist = distancias[c.x][c.y];
                        descubierto[c.x][c.y] = false;
                        camino.add(c);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return fin;
    }

    public ArrayList<Casilla> adyacente(Casilla c) {
        ArrayList<Casilla> alrededor = new ArrayList<>();
        int ant;
        if (c.x > 0 && c.x < canvas.columnas - 1 && c.y > 0 && c.y < canvas.filas) {
            ant = canvas.paredes[c.y][c.x + 1];
            if ((ant != 7) && (ant != 8) && (ant != 9) && (ant != 11)
                    && (ant != 12) && (ant != 13) && (ant != 14) && (ant != 15)
                    && (ant != 16)) {
                alrededor.add(new Casilla(c.x + 1, c.y, 3));
            }
            ant = canvas.paredes[c.y][c.x - 1];
            if ((ant != 7) && (ant != 8) && (ant != 9) && (ant != 11)
                    && (ant != 12) && (ant != 13) && (ant != 14) && (ant != 15)
                    && (ant != 16)) {
                alrededor.add(new Casilla(c.x - 1, c.y, 3));
            }
            ant = canvas.paredes[c.y + 1][c.x];
            if ((ant != 7) && (ant != 8) && (ant != 9) && (ant != 11)
                    && (ant != 12) && (ant != 13) && (ant != 14) && (ant != 15)
                    && (ant != 16)) {
                alrededor.add(new Casilla(c.x, c.y + 1, 3));
            }
            ant = canvas.paredes[c.y - 1][c.x];
            if ((ant != 7) && (ant != 8) && (ant != 9) && (ant != 11)
                    && (ant != 12) && (ant != 13) && (ant != 14) && (ant != 15)
                    && (ant != 16)) {
                alrededor.add(new Casilla(c.x, c.y - 1, 3));
            }
        }
        return alrededor;
    }

    private void arriba() {
        anterior = canvas.paredes[canvas.g1.y - 1][canvas.g1.x];
        if ((anterior != 7) && (anterior != 8) && (anterior != 9) && (anterior != 11)
                && (anterior != 12) && (anterior != 13) && (anterior != 14) && (anterior != 15)
                && (anterior != 16) && noFantasma(canvas.gh1[canvas.g1.y - 1][canvas.g1.x],
                        canvas.gh2[canvas.g1.y - 1][canvas.g1.x],
                        canvas.gh3[canvas.g1.y - 1][canvas.g1.x],
                        canvas.gh4[canvas.g1.y - 1][canvas.g1.x])) {//Si no hay muro ni otro fantasma
            canvas.gh1[canvas.g1.y][canvas.g1.x] = 0;
            canvas.g1.y = canvas.g1.y - 1;//Cambio fila
            canvas.gh1[canvas.g1.y][canvas.g1.x] = 3;//Dibulo
        } else if (anterior == 2) {
            if (canvas.g1.owned) {
                canvas.gh1[canvas.g1.y][canvas.g1.x] = 0;
                canvas.g1.x = 12;
                canvas.g1.y = 15;
                canvas.gh1[15][12] = 3;
                canvas.g1.owned = false;
                ventana.npuntuacion += 200;
            } else if (canvas.g1.owned == false) {
                if (canvas.vidas <= 1) {
                    canvas.vidas = 0;
                } else {
                    vidaMenos();
                }
                ventana.npuntuacion -= 200;
            }
        }
    }

    private void derecha() {
        try {
            anterior = canvas.paredes[canvas.g1.y][canvas.g1.x + 1];
        } catch (Exception e) {
            anterior = 17;
        }
        if ((anterior != 7) && (anterior != 8) && (anterior != 9) && (anterior != 11)
                && (anterior != 12) && (anterior != 13) && (anterior != 14) && (anterior != 15)
                && (anterior != 16) && noFantasma(canvas.gh1[canvas.g1.y][canvas.g1.x + 1],
                        canvas.gh2[canvas.g1.y][canvas.g1.x + 1],
                        canvas.gh3[canvas.g1.y][canvas.g1.x + 1],
                        canvas.gh4[canvas.g1.y][canvas.g1.x + 1])) {//Si no hay muro
            try {
                canvas.gh1[canvas.g1.y][canvas.g1.x] = 0;
                canvas.g1.x = canvas.g1.x + 1;//Cambio fila
                canvas.gh1[canvas.g1.y][canvas.g1.x] = 3;//Dibulo
            } catch (Exception e) {
                canvas.g1.x = canvas.g1.x - 1;
                canvas.paredes[canvas.g1.y][canvas.g1.x] = 17;
                canvas.g1.x = canvas.g1.x - 27;
                canvas.gh1[canvas.g1.y][canvas.g1.x] = 3;//Dibulo
            }
        } else if (anterior == 2) {
            if (canvas.g1.owned) {
                canvas.gh1[canvas.g1.y][canvas.g1.x] = 0;
                canvas.g1.x = 12;
                canvas.g1.y = 15;
                canvas.gh1[15][12] = 3;
                canvas.g1.owned = false;
                ventana.npuntuacion += 200;
            } else if (canvas.g1.owned == false) {
                if (canvas.vidas <= 1) {
                    canvas.vidas = 0;
                } else {
                    vidaMenos();
                }
                ventana.npuntuacion -= 200;
            }
        }
    }

    private void abajo() {
        anterior = canvas.paredes[canvas.g1.y + 1][canvas.g1.x];
        if ((anterior != 7) && (anterior != 8) && (anterior != 9) && (anterior != 11)
                && (anterior != 12) && (anterior != 13) && (anterior != 14) && (anterior != 15)
                && (anterior != 16) && noFantasma(canvas.gh1[canvas.g1.y + 1][canvas.g1.x],
                        canvas.gh2[canvas.g1.y + 1][canvas.g1.x],
                        canvas.gh3[canvas.g1.y + 1][canvas.g1.x],
                        canvas.gh4[canvas.g1.y + 1][canvas.g1.x])) {//Si no hay muro
            canvas.gh1[canvas.g1.y][canvas.g1.x] = 0;
            canvas.g1.y = canvas.g1.y + 1;//Cambio fila
            canvas.gh1[canvas.g1.y][canvas.g1.x] = 3;//Dibulo
        } else if (anterior == 2) {
            if (canvas.g1.owned) {
                canvas.gh1[canvas.g1.y][canvas.g1.x] = 0;
                canvas.g1.x = 12;
                canvas.g1.y = 15;
                canvas.gh1[15][12] = 3;
                canvas.g1.owned = false;
                ventana.npuntuacion += 200;
            } else if (canvas.g1.owned == false) {
                if (canvas.vidas <= 1) {
                    canvas.vidas = 0;
                } else {
                    vidaMenos();
                }
                ventana.npuntuacion -= 200;
            }
        }
    }

    private void izquierda() {
        try {
            anterior = canvas.paredes[canvas.g1.y][canvas.g1.x - 1];
        } catch (Exception e) {
            anterior = 18;
        }
        if ((anterior != 7) && (anterior != 8) && (anterior != 9) && (anterior != 11)
                && (anterior != 12) && (anterior != 13) && (anterior != 14) && (anterior != 15)
                && (anterior != 16) && noFantasma(canvas.gh1[canvas.g1.y][canvas.g1.x - 1],
                        canvas.gh2[canvas.g1.y][canvas.g1.x - 1],
                        canvas.gh3[canvas.g1.y][canvas.g1.x - 1],
                        canvas.gh4[canvas.g1.y][canvas.g1.x - 1])) {//Si no hay muro
            try {
                canvas.gh1[canvas.g1.y][canvas.g1.x] = 0;
                canvas.g1.x = canvas.g1.x - 1;//Cambio fila
                canvas.gh1[canvas.g1.y][canvas.g1.x] = 3;//Dibulo
            } catch (Exception e) {
                canvas.g1.x = canvas.g1.x + 1;
                canvas.paredes[canvas.g1.y][canvas.g1.x] = 17;
                canvas.g1.x = canvas.g1.x + 27;
                canvas.gh1[canvas.g1.y][canvas.g1.x] = 3;//Dibulo
            }
        } else if (anterior == 2) {
            if (canvas.g1.owned) {
                canvas.gh1[canvas.g1.y][canvas.g1.x] = 0;
                canvas.g1.x = 12;
                canvas.g1.y = 15;
                canvas.gh1[15][12] = 3;
                canvas.g1.owned = false;
                ventana.npuntuacion += 200;
            } else if (canvas.g1.owned == false) {
                if (canvas.vidas <= 1) {
                    canvas.vidas = 0;
                } else {
                    vidaMenos();
                }
                ventana.npuntuacion -= 200;
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean noFantasma(int f1, int f2, int f3, int f4) {
        if (f1 != 3 && f2 != 4 && f3 != 5 && f4 != 6) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void vidaMenos() {
        canvas.vidas--;
        canvas.gh1[canvas.g1.y][canvas.g1.x] = 0;
        canvas.g1.x = 12;
        canvas.g1.y = 15;
        canvas.gh1[15][12] = 3;
        canvas.gh2[canvas.g2.y][canvas.g2.x] = 0;
        canvas.g2.x = 13;
        canvas.g2.y = 15;
        canvas.gh2[15][13] = 4;
        canvas.gh3[canvas.g3.y][canvas.g3.x] = 0;
        canvas.g3.x = 14;
        canvas.g3.y = 15;
        canvas.gh3[15][14] = 5;
        canvas.gh4[canvas.g4.y][canvas.g4.x] = 0;
        canvas.g4.x = 15;
        canvas.g4.y = 15;
        canvas.gh4[15][15] = 6;
        canvas.paredes[canvas.pacman.y][canvas.pacman.x] = 0;
        canvas.pacman.x = 13;
        canvas.pacman.y = 23;
        canvas.paredes[23][13] = 2;
    }
}
```

I also know that it could be better done, and probably many of you will want to kick my ass... but I only had one week to do the full project and I am a complete noob in java, so I did my best.
Have a nice day :)